Remove special character and units form Pandas column name with Python
I'm working on a script to convert a data file from one format to another. I need to remove the special characters from the column headers.
I am using Pandas to read a CSV file with the below structure. I'm looking for a tidy way to remove the [units] form the column name.
Data File:
Date        ,Time        ,app1_sum [Ml] ,app1_q [l/s]  ,app1_h [m] ,app1_a [m²] ,app1_v [m/s] ,app1_t_water [°C]
02.10.2024  ,19:05:00    ,57293.336     ,620.78        ,0.436      ,0.586       ,1.059        ,18.2

My goal is to have column names stripped down to their simplest form:
Date,Time,app1_sum,app1_q,app1_h,app1_a,app1_v,app1_t_water
My current approach is to remove the brackers first, then remove the remining units one at a time.
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('[', '')
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(']', '')
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' Ml', '') 

I also tried to use regex to remove one unit at a time, this works but doesn't feel right.
df.rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub(r'\[Ml\]', '', x), inplace=True)
df.rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub(r'\[l/s\]', '', x), inplace=True)
df.rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub(r'\[m\]', '', x), inplace=True)
df.rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub(r'\[m²\]', '', x), inplace=True)
df.rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub(r'\[m/s\]', '', x), inplace=True)
df.rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub(r'\[°C\]', '', x), inplace=True)


One tip if I may, avoid naming the columns with signs like celsius or squared

You can use the following code to replace all brackets and their content in the columns names:
df.rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub(r'\[[^\]]+\]', '', x), inplace=True)

\[ will match the opening bracket [
[^\]]+ will match an abtritrary number of every character except ]
\] will match the closing bracket
The \ are needed to escape the brackets since they are part of regex syntax

You can just split on a space and keep the first item for each column name.
df.columns = [c.split(' ')[0] for c in df.columns]


You can rename with a regex to match any unit of the form  [xx] and remove it with str.replace:
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' *\[.*\]', '', regex=True)

New index after replacement:
Index(['Date', 'Time', 'app1_sum', 'app1_q', 'app1_h', 'app1_a', 'app1_v',
       'app1_t_water'],
      dtype='object')

Alternatively, use a custom function and rename:
import re
def remove_unit(name):
    return re.sub(' *\[.*\]', '', name)

out = df.rename(columns=remove_unit)

# or in place:
# df.rename(columns=remove_unit, inplace=True)

